# how can I use Aqua Emacs's Chinese font in Carbon Emacs?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, carbon-emacs

I love the Chinese font support in AquaEmacs `(with core: "GNU Emacs 23.2.50.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, NS apple-appkit-949.54)`. Is there anyway I can hack in and use its Chinese font in Carbon Emacs `(with core: "GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0)?`

Answer (score 2):

Emacs does not include its own Chinese font, it uses ones already installed on the system.

That said, the font support changed drastically between Emacs 22 and 23, and I don't know what support was like in Carbon Emacs for non Latin fonts.  Maybe you just need to use a different format for the name of the font, or maybe you need to define a fontset to use that font for Chinese text.

Hacking the Emacs 23 font support into Emacs 22 for Carbon would be a big project, why don't you just use Emacs 23?  There is still a version of Carbon Emacs being maintained if you have something against the Cocoa/Nextstep port that is the current official version available for OS X.